# how to send response to another component

Tags: angular

can any one please tell me i am sending 'id' to backend based on that id, i am getting user details. I am storing this userdetails in x object. that x object i am sending to another component using BehaviorSubject but data is not sending to another component. anyone please tell me what is the issue. what i need to put.

reviewcomponent.html

```
<i class="fas fa-edit" routerLink='/dashboard-info/review-edit'
```

reviewcomponent.ts

```
editUserDetails:any=[];
    editIssue(id, detail) {
      alert(detail);
      let data = {
        _id: detail,
      };
      this.accountService.editreviewDetail(data).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.editUserDetails = response;
          let data1=this.editUserDetails
              this.accountService.sendedit(data1)
        },
        err => {
          console.error('User Not found');
        }) 
    }
```

accountservice

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
    private user=new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    cast=this.user.asObservable();
    public apiPath: string;//Api URL where we need to send our data & perform related operations
    constructor(ds: DataService, private http: HttpClient) {
        this.apiPath = ds.apiPath;
    }

    sendedit(newUser){
        return this.user.next(newUser)
    }

}
```

reviewedit.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.cast.subscribe(user=>this.editUserDetails=user);
    console.log(this.editUserDetails);
}
```

nothing is showing when I `console.log(this.editUserDetails)` in reviewedit.component.ts.
here editUserDetails:any=[];

Comment: use `Output` it will work

Comment: please tell me where should i use Output?

Comment: which component emits the  values, use in that  and accept those emitted values in the child component

Comment: I am sending data using output.
      let Output=this.editUserDetails;
          this.accountService.sendedit(Output);
    },
i use this. if you are not saying this, please tell me in code. my code structure is in above.

Answer (score -1):

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject.

You can and should subscribe directly to the BehaviorSubject. That way, you will always get the current value. There's no need to cast it to an Observable.

So in your **rewiewedit.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.user
        .subscribe(user => {
            this.editUserDetails=user;
            console.log(this.editUserDetails);
    });
}
```

PS: don't forget to make your BehaviorSubject public.

Comment: Not working. i remove cast and add public in BehaviorSubject

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to move the logging inside the subscription so that every time a new value is emitted, you log it. Try it now.

Comment: Well, you have to emit something. Try initializing the BehaviorSubject with some other value in order to see if it works.